# Reflection with multiple parameter types

Tags: c#

I have a database table that contains two text fields: methodname and methodparameters. The values from the table are stored in a dictionary.

Each methodname value corresponds to an image filter method in a c# class, and each methodparameters is a comma-delimited list of numeric values.

I want to use reflection to call methodname with its corresponding list of methodparameters.

Here is a portion of image filter class:

```
namespace ImageFilters
{
  public class Filters
  {

    private static Bitmap mBMP;

    public Bitmap BMP { 
        get
        {
            return mBMP;
        }
        set
        {
            mBMP = value;
        }
    }

    public static void FilterColors(string[] paramlist)
    {

        mBMP = FilterColors(mBMP, 
                            Convert.ToInt16(paramlist[0].ToString()),
                            Convert.ToInt16(paramlist[1].ToString()),
                            Convert.ToInt16(paramlist[2].ToString()),
                            Convert.ToInt16(paramlist[3].ToString()),
                            Convert.ToInt16(paramlist[4].ToString()),
                            Convert.ToInt16(paramlist[5].ToString())
                            );

    }

    public static Bitmap FilterColors(Bitmap bmp, int RedFrom,int RedTo, 
                       int GreenFrom, int GreenTo, int BlueFrom, int BlueTo,
                       byte RedFill = 255, byte GreenFill = 255, 
                       byte BlueFill = 255, bool FillOutside = true)
    {
        AForge.Imaging.Filters.ColorFiltering f = new AForge.Imaging.Filters.ColorFiltering();
        f.FillOutsideRange = FillOutside;
        f.FillColor = new AForge.Imaging.RGB(RedFill, GreenFill, BlueFill);
        f.Red = new AForge.IntRange(RedFrom, RedTo);
        f.Green = new AForge.IntRange(GreenFrom, GreenTo);
        f.Blue = new AForge.IntRange(BlueFrom, BlueTo);
        return f.Apply(bmp);
    }
```

Here is the code I am using that uses Reflection:

```
    private static void ApplyFilters(ref Bitmap bmp, 
                      dictionaries.FilterFields pFilters)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < pFilters.Detail.Length; i++)
        {
            Type t = typeof(ImageFilters.Filters);
            MethodInfo mi = t.GetMethod(pFilters.Detail[i].MethodName);
            ImageFilters.Filters f = new ImageFilters.Filters();
            f.BMP = bmp;

            string[] parameters = pFilters.Detail[i].MethodParameters.Split(',');
            mi.Invoke(f, parameters);
        }
    }
```

Each image is processed with no filters, and with two sets of different filters (from the database).  The following loop handles the filters:

```
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, dictionaries.FilterFields> item 
                 in dictionaries.Filters)
        {
            bmp = OriginalBMP;

            ApplyFilters(ref bmp, item.Value);

        }
```

My problem is that when it hits ApplyFilters in the loop, it gives me the following error:

"Method not found: 'Void ImageFilters.Filters.set_BMP(System.Drawing.Bitmap)'.  It does not even allow me to step into the ApplyFilters method.

I definitely do not have a method called "set_BMP" in my database table.

Any ideas?

Comment: set_BMP is a setter for a property, not a method

Comment: @Richard, you're going to have to tell us what `pFilters.Detail[i].MethodName` is with 100% certainty.  (print it out to the console or something and copy and paste the value)

Comment: *>>It does not even allow me to step into the ApplyFilters method* Can you put a break point in there? But yes, I don't think you can address property setters as methods, you need to access them as properties.

Comment: I am a no time calling this method.  That is just what the DB says.

Comment: Yes it seems that it comes from the DB this way. You'll have to accommodate for this and call it differently (that is a a property setter not as a method).

Comment: I apologize.  I meant to say..."That is just what the *ERROR* says.  My DB does not hae a set_BMP method nor does my class.

Comment: When I comment out the line with 'f.BMP = bmp', I am able to set a break point in ApplyFilters.  How else would I be able to pass in my image as a parameter using reflection with all my other parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is a JIT error. At runtime, you are attempting to call `ApplyFilters`. The runtime then tries to compile the `ApplyFilters` method from MSIL to machine code. At that point in time, it sees that you're using a property called `BMP` on the `Filters` class, but it can't find it (or can't find the setter). Therefore it can't compile the method and can't call into it, which is why your breakpoint isn't being hit.

It appears the `BMP` property (or its setter) does not exist at runtime. This usually happens because a different version of the assembly is being loaded at runtime -- you compile it with one version that has this property, but when running it, the referenced assembly doesn't contain that property.

Double-check that the assemblies that exist in the directory are up-to-date and are the correct versions you're expecting.

Comment: Are all of the code snippets from your original post in the same assembly?

Comment: And do you have more than one artifact named `ImageFilters`? In the code above, `ImageFilters` is a namespace. Do you also have any classes or properties named `ImageFilters`?

Comment: The Image Filter class is in a different project from the class that contains ApplyFilter.  They are all part of the same solution, and the class that contains ApplyFilter has the ImageFilter project as a reference.

Comment: I don't have any classes or properties named ImageFilters.

Comment: Triple-check the location of the assemblies at runtime (`typeof(SomeClass).Assembly.Location`). Then try opening the assembly that's supposed to contain ImageFilters.Filters.BMP in Reflector and verify that the class is what you're expecting. I can't think of any reason the JIT compile would fail other than the assembly not being what you think it is.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45153/discussion-between-richard-and-michael-gunter)

Answer (score 0):

Your `BMP` is not a method, it is a property. Get the property then get the `.SetMethod` of the property.

```
PropertyInfo pi = type.GetProperty("BMP");
System.Reflection.MethodInfo mi = pi.SetMethod;

string[] parameters = pFilters.Detail[i].MethodParameters.Split(',');
mi.Invoke(f, parameters);
```

Comment: I am at no time trying to call BMP as a method.  I do not have Set_BMP defined anywhere in my image filter class, and I have no idea where it came from.

Comment: This is not the problem. The `ApplyFilters` method is the code that contains the reflection, and the runtime is failing to compile the `ApplyFilters` method.

Comment: your Invoke is not calling it?  What is your invoke calling then?

Comment: why is your error say "Void ImageFilters.Filters.set_BMP(System.Drawing.Bitmap)",  why is Void not void?   e.g. lowercase void

Comment: `System.Void` is the runtime type associated with the C# `void` keyword. You guys are barking up the wrong tree here. This is not a problem with reflection. The reflection code is never being executed because the ApplyFilters method cannot compile.

Comment: I agree with you Gunter.  It is never even getting to the reflection.